# detecting multiple browsers and versions using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I’m currently trying to apply a rule to several modern browsers. My browser detection basically works like this (example is Safari ≥ 5, this works):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Version/(\d).*Safari/
RewriteCond %1 >4
RewriteRule ...
```

Now I want to chain multiple of those detections together, and apply the rule if any of them is matched. I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Version/(\d).*Safari/
RewriteCond %1 >4 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome/(\d\d)
RewriteCond %1 >22
RewriteRule ...
```

This does not work (I suspect because [OR] only applies to the next rule, not the next two). Is there a way to make this work, or do I have to list the RewriteRule one time for each browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can't wrap parentheses around RewriteCond directives, so you can't have a set of conditions such that you check ((A and B) or (C and D)). So you will need to use a pair of tests with a RewriteRule directive for each browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `[OR]` directive doesn't affect multiple conditions chained together. You need to separate the 2 chains of conditions and duplicate the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Version/(\d).*Safari/
RewriteCond %1 >4
RewriteRule ...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome/(\d\d)
RewriteCond %1 >22
RewriteRule ...
```